# How to make flickr embedded video responsive while using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video, flickr

I need to make the embedded video responsive. I tried the solution [introduced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787444/using-twitter-bootstrap-how-to-make-an-embedded-video-responsive) with no success. The width of video stays the same and not scales down making it look out of bounds on mobile device. How to make flickr video responsive?

Due to that fact that Chrome wasn't able to copy source code inside iframe, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="flickr-embed-photo">` has an inline style with a width. Apparently it takes it from its window size, and the "window" is the iframe. And the iframe has an inline style attribute with heights and width... can you try something like

```
iframe {
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using latest Bootstrap 4.6, you can use classes from the [Embeds utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/). Something like the below should work but you may need to select the proper class for your embed proportions and remove the `flickr-embed-frame` since flickr-embed JS could be placing inline code there.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://your-flickr-embed-url" ></iframe>
</div>
```